# Linux - script to find the line which is not JSON format

Tags: json, linux

I have following file, with each line being a `JSON` format.

```
{"id": 123, "name": "Tom"}
{"id": 124, "name": "Jerry"}
{"id": 125, "name": "Ken"}
...
...# there are 200000 rows in this file
```

In some lines, the JSON may not be properly formed. Could be either containing a new line character, or the quotes are not properly closed. Or could be other reasons.

How can I find those lines in Linux more efficiently, other than manually checking line by line for 200000 times?

Comment: Edit your question to show **the exact text** of the error message you are currently getting. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the lines of a file and check them for validity with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
linenum=1
while IFS="" read -r line
do
    echo "$line" | jq > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "invalid json on line $linenum"
        echo "$line"
    fi
    linenum=$((linenum + 1))
done < data.txt
```